# iPhone iAds: Very inconsistent, sometimes bannerViewDidLoadAd does not get called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

So I show my iAd banners when I get a callback to:
'bannerViewDidLoadAd'

But I've noticed that sometimes this doesn't get called. I have a constant high-speed 
internet connection but if I run my app 10 times. 4 of out 10 times it won't show the iAds (i.e., bannerViewDidLoadAd does not get called).

Has anyone else experienced this (and what have you done about this)?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design (I'm assuming you're still running in a dev environment) so that you can test your application when an iAd is available and when an iAd isn't available.

> While you are developing your
>   application, iAd Network sends test
>   advertisements to your application. To
>   assist you in validating your
>   implementation, the iAd Network
>   occasionally returns errors to test
>   your error handling code. You can also
>   test your error handling support by
>   turning your device’s wireless
>   capability off.

per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW4)

Comment: It's something to be very prepared for, in that it will fail to get called many times in the real world as well; many friends running iAds (I'm not doing so yet) see a fill rate of about 10%, so your bannerViewDidLoadAd will only be called 1 in 10 times. There just aren't enough paid ads in the system yet.